# How to setup react app with SCSS? (Errors)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, node-sass

I am trying to setup my react project so I can use SASS in the SCSS format.

This is in my webpack.config.dev.js:

```
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          require.resolve('style-loader'),
          {
            loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: require.resolve('sass-loader'),
          }
        ]
      }
```

I import the scss files into my jsx in two different ways:

```
import './index.scss';
import css from './ModalWrapper.scss';
```

When I run the app I am currently getting the error:

```
./src/index.scss
Module build failed: 
body {
^
      Invalid CSS after "m": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "module.exports = __"
      in /pathtoapp/web/src/index.scss (line 1, column 1)
```

It appears me, that one, react is trying to interpret the SCSS as CSS which should work. In addition, react believes that body is not valid CSS. There, I would believe that neither CSS or SCSS are being loaded correctly.

Any help would be appreciated. There are quite a few unanswered questions to this problem.

Comment: Are you importing each scss file into a different component for - component styles, or do you just import the root scss file in your root app file?

Comment: I import the scss file into a different component for component styles. However, I would also like to have a couple global scss files for constants and fonts.

Comment: Well its a little more complex than a simple answer, but I think this article will help guide you through installing and getting it setup -> https://medium.com/@srinisoundar/setting-up-environment-for-react-sass-es2015-babel-with-webpack-2f77445129

Comment: Why are you require.resolve on the loaders? Just do loader: 'saas-loader' and similar for other loaders in your config above.

Comment: I've tried that as well @VishalMalik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'style-loader'
        }, {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: true,
            sourceMap: true,
            localIdentName: "[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
          },
        }, {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            outputStyle: "expanded",
            sourceMap: true,
          },
        }]
      },
```

Answer (score 19):

If you are on Webpack 3, add this to `module.rules`

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: [
      require.resolve('style-loader'),
      require.resolve('css-loader'),
      require.resolve('sass-loader'),
    ]
},
```

And then add the file loader and make sure to add `.scss` to the array of the key `exclude` like this

```
{
        loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
        // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
        // it's runtime that would otherwise processed through "file" loader.
        // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
        // by webpacks internal loaders.
        exclude: [/\.js$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/, /\.scss$/,],
        options: {
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
        },
}
```

And of course, make sure you have `style-loader`, `sass-loader`, `css-loader` and `file-loader` in you package.json. This code snippet worked for me when using the latest version of `create-react-app`.

Comment: Saver~! I spent 2 hours on finding out what's wrong in my webpack config and this one solved my problem~! thanks~!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the other answers are just as good, but for maximum brevity, this works for me (I erased some of the internal webpack.config.dev.js comments presumably made by the create react folks):

```
module: {
strictExportPresence: true,
rules: [
        {
            test: /\.scss/,
            use: ['style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        },...
```

I don't know if it matters, but I put this on the top. Also, yes, make sure to add the scss file to the excluded array as mentioned above.